# Is it really a good idea to allocate part of a portfolio to international stock funds?

Tags: mutual-funds, international

I've heard this advice and held an international fund and a developing markets fund (vtiax, veiex) through most of last year.  These investments were down most of the time that I owned them, and are still down.

Are these really important for a "balanced portfolio", or am I better off sticking to domestic markets (which did much better for me)?

Comment: I made the same experience; but you need to look at multiple years, not just one.

Comment: You ask for advice based on your bad history of ONE YEAR for something that is supposed to be a long term investment?

Comment: @TomTom - you could have phrased that as a helpful comment / answer, but you chose not to.  Anyway, I understand the timeframe is short, and I am asking for the *general* case as my second paragraph shows.